# How does Twitter OAuth work in Android?

Tags: android, url, twitter, callback

I have been searching for an answer for quite some time, and I have admit that I am pretty stuck. I am attempting to implement Twitter in my application and have found it somewhat challenging. It seems the way to do it is to register my app with Twitter(I have already done so) as a Browser application. I don't know what to use for my callback url though. I really want to just return to my current activity in the application, and not be redirected to a callback url. What should I put for that? I am pretty stuck...

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This is how it works... you do the call to twitter authentication URL (by opening a web browser). The URL of the authentication must contain the callback URL. A callback URL usually looks like this: `x-your-application-name-oauth-twitter://callback` (*).

Second step is to add an intent filter to your `Activity` (implementing twitter auth requires you to know how Android works (unless you find a tutorial that does everything for you, but I think that's not the case seems you seem to be a smart guy, aren't you?)). Whatever, you do so by adding something like this in your manifest:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
    <data android:scheme="x-your-application-name-oauth-twitter" android:host="callback"/>
</intent-filter>
```

This is basically a way to say to Android OS: "*hey dude, I can handle any URL that looks like `x-your-application-name-oauth-twitter://callback`*". That way, once user has authenticated, twitter will call that URL and your application will reclaim the control.

Usually, your activity must be created with the `android:launchMode="singleTask"` tag, then you must override the `onNewIntent` method of your activity that will be called once your application has the control again. Inside the `Intent` you will find information about the callback.

(*) Building the URL that you must launch (and that will allow users to authenticate) is somehow difficult. OAuth is a good but kind of hard to learn standard. So, you can use third-party libraries that will help you on this. You could, for instance, use Oauth Signpost java library. However, I would recommend you to stick to twitter4j library that will help you with OAuth and also allows you to interact with Twitter API.

Comment: Question : please can you tell , me what to put in , android:scheme="x-your-application-name-oauth-twitter"

Comment: If your app were called FooBar, you can put `android:scheme="foo-bar-oauth-twitter"`; if your app were called Tushar Pandey, you would use `android:scheme="tushar-pandey-oauth-twitter"`, etc.

Comment: Is "callback" literally that or should it be replaced with something?

Comment: It can/should be replaced

Comment: The scheme part: android:scheme="x-your-application-name-oauth-twitter" is the only working one for me after googling the entire day, thank you.

Comment: Error while setting callback URL at twitter side. I used 'x-my-application-name-oauth-twitter://callback' (Error
The client application failed validation: Not a valid callback URL format)

Comment: answer is obsolete.
try https://stackoverflow.com/q/50601607/5243472

Answer (score 1):

As of GDPR in place, Sign in with Twitter will only be possible in app with whitelist callback URLs. Mobile apps with app-specific protocols must use just the protocol. For example, please use **twittersdk://** as opposed to **twittersdk://authorize** for callback URLs within your app settings on [apps.twitter.com](http://apps.twitter.com)

For detailed example please see below:

1. To get started Visit [apps.twitter.com](http://apps.twitter.com) to create the app. Provide details like Application name, application description, application website, callback URLs (as mentioned above please use

> twittersdk://

as callback URL in case of ANDROID App) and Allow this application to be used to Sign in with Twitter.

2. After successfully creating an app on twitter developer account, add the following dependencies to your application's Gradle config (usually app/build.gradle).

> compile 'com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:3.1.1'

3. Initialize Twitter Kit **(optional)**

If using a custom Application class you can initialize Twitter Kit in the onCreate() method.

```java
public class CustomApplication {
  public void onCreate() {
    Twitter.initialize(this);
   }
 }
```

4. add your **Consumer Key**(API key) and **Consumer Secret**(API secret) to your application resources. You can get this within your app settings on [apps.twitter.com](http://apps.twitter.com)

```html
<resources>
      <string android:name="com.twitter.sdk.android.CONSUMER_KEY">XXXXXXXXXXX</string>
      <string android:name="com.twitter.sdk.android.CONSUMER_SECRET">XXXXXXXXXXX</string>
    </resources>
```

5. Inside your layout, add a Login button with the following code:

```html
<com.twitter.sdk.android.core.identity.TwitterLoginButton
     android:id="@+id/login_button"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

6. In the Activity or Fragment that displays the button, you need to create and attach a Callback to the Login Button.

```java
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.Callback;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.Result;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterException;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterSession;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.identity.TwitterLoginButton;
       ...

     loginButton = (TwitterLoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
     loginButton.setCallback(new Callback<TwitterSession>() {
        @Override
        public void success(Result<TwitterSession> result) {
            // Do something with result, which provides a TwitterSession for making API calls
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(TwitterException exception) {
            // Do something on failure
        }
     });
```

7. Next, pass the result of the authentication Activity back to the button:

```java
 @Override protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int
 resultCode, Intent data) {
     super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

     // Pass the activity result to the login button.
     loginButton.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data); 
}
```

OR If using the TwitterLoginButton in a Fragment, use the following steps instead. Inside the Activity hosting the Fragment, pass the result from the Activity to the Fragment.

```java
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        // Pass the activity result to the fragment, which will then pass the result to the login
        // button.
        Fragment fragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.your_fragment_id);
        if (fragment != null) {
            fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }
```