# Twitter Call back URL

Tags: swift, twitter, authentication

I am working with twitter SDK to integrate with in ios app.When i follow all the step and create the customer key and put it in my app.When I run the app it show 
"[TwitterKit] did encounter error with message

> "Error obtaining user auth token.": Error Domain=TWTRLogInErrorDomain
>   Code=-1 "Callback URL not approved for this client application.
>   Approved callback URLs can be adjusted in your application
>   settings" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Callback URL
>   not approved for this client application. Approved callback URLs can
>   be adjusted in your application settings"

How to resolve this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50961255/5523205

Answer (score 53):

I had the same problem and the TwitterKit documentation is not accurate or Twitter has changed their policies. In any case, on the Twitter Apps site, the callback URL has to be set very specifically. The callback URL should be in the format:

```
twitterkit-{consumer/api key}://
```

For example:

```
twitterkit-128238aKjqlp123AKdasdf://
```

Also, this needs to be registered in your Info.plist exactly the same:

```
<dict>
<key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>twitterkit-128238aKjqlp123AKdasdf</string>
</array>
</dict>
```

More documentation is listed here: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/callback_url.html

Comment: Life saver, I don't understand how is twitter not stating this in their documentation. Thanks.

Comment: @AmroShafie i have the same error, i don't know how to solve it suppose that API key is 123 then the url callback should be: twitterkit-123://

Comment: @Al-shimaaAdel Did you add this callback url in both your app and apps.twitter.com platform under settings tab ?

Comment: nice answer with example Thanks

Comment: Nice, it was very helpful. You should point into add the correct CallBack in the Twitter Dev Site as:   twitterkit-"consumerKey"://

Comment: stuck in "Redirecting you to the application". But before safari gives me warning about invalid url.

Comment: I have tried to add URL and URL Schema in info.plist file but I am still facing same issue I am using firebase SDK for twitter login

Answer (score 30):

I just added on callback url field `twitterkit-<api/consumer Key>://`.
If you have an apiKey like `abc` you should add `twitterkit-abc://`. This work for iOS, for Android just add `twittersdk://`.

Comment: You sir, are an immeasurable life-saver. You should know that :)

Geez, if only Twitter would take a bit more care of us, 3rd-party developers, without whom the platform would be absolutely nothing...
Is it too much to ask for just proper documentation *with your official SDK* ?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.

Comment: This  is the best answer. What a trick. I was struggling a lot. Just worked for me. Thanks.

Comment: Great and precise answer, helpful for both android and ios. Thanks a lot !!

Comment: For iOS you have to add this  twitterkit-consumerkey://

Answer (score 18):

To Fix this issue do as below:

**[Mandatory]**

Add CallbackURL into the dashboard as below format:

**For iOS:**

twitterkit-CONSUMERKEY://

**For Android:**

twittersdk://

**Help Link:**

https://twittercommunity.com/t/ios-twitter-login-error-code-415/107775

[ **Note:** Please replace your consumer key in place of words "CONSUMERKEY" in above format]

Comment: I am using Android Studio and this worked for me as well. Just added twittersdk:// to the CallbackURL field in apps.twitter.com. Thanks.

Comment: I have added CallbackURL but I am still facing the same issue I am using firebase SDK for twitter login.

Comment: if you have the app installed - it's opening - but gives error - Opening link in Safari browser, as the host is not whitelisted: twitterkit-1234://callback?app=1234&oauth_token=2&oauth_verifier=2

Answer (score 4):

My solution: I hope it's useful. [image]

Answer (score 1):

Go to https://apps.twitter.com

Then in the "Settings" tab of your app.
Fill the "Callback URLs" form.

According to this documentation i guess you just have to enter a valid URL :
https://github.com/twitter/twitter-kit-ios/wiki/Installation

> NOTE: Although the callback URL will not be requested by Twitter Kit in your app, it must be set to a valid URL for the app to work with the SDK.

Answer (score 1):

Hey everyone here is a simple fix that worked for me.

Go to: https://apps.twitter.com
Go into the settings tab. 
Under Terms of Service URL uncheck the box that says:
"Unable Callback Locking"
Now test your app.

Comment: Saved my life. Thank you! I had this issue on android for devices without twitter app installed.

Comment: @BoldijarPaul I am doing the same but still facing the issue. can you help

Comment: @UsamaSadiq for me it worked by unchecking that box, because on android it would show up the webview..I can't help you more than this..sorry

Comment: there is no option called Unable Callback Locking in twitter app details

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the solution for my case. Hope it'll help someone else

Put this in URL Callback field.

**twittersdk://**

Refer: https://github.com/twitter/twitter-kit-android/issues/135

Comment: But what if you're not using the (now retired) twitterkit ?