# login with twitter callback url error

Tags: ios, twitter

I want to login to app with twitter, i follow [this documentation](https://github.com/twitter/twitter-kit-ios/wiki/Migrating-from-iOS-Social-Framework)
but i got this error

> [TwitterKit] did encounter error with message "Error obtaining user auth token.": Error Domain=TWTRLogInErrorDomain Code=-1 "Callback URL not approved for this client application. Approved callback URLs can be adjusted in your application settings" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Callback URL not approved for this client application. Approved callback URLs can be adjusted in your application settings}
>   error:  Optional("Request failed: forbidden (403)")

i found this answer in twitter developer documentation

> If you do receive this error message, please check the URL that you are using with the callback_url parameter in your oauth/request_token call and make sure that this URL has been whitelisted in your app settings on apps.twitter.com.

[and this is the link](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/callback_url.html)

but i don't understand that, i don't know what to do 
any help please ?

Comment: Please check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50601607/twitter-call-back-url

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved it, I set Callback URL in that format `twitterkit-{api key}://`  suppose api key is 1234 then the Callback URL should be `twitterkit-1234://`

Comment: how to get api key

Comment: @dev_mg99 it is the consumer key in the twitter application you created

Comment: Thanks for reply but your method is not working for me.i have used "twittersdk://" this is working for me

Comment: @Al-shimaaAdel I have used twitterkit-{api key}:// but still I am getting the same error, it will reflect in my app immediately or it will take some time?

Comment: @dev_mg99 I have to write only twittersdk:// or I have to add the api key to it??

Comment: @Sudhansu you could write wittersdk:// only or use this format  twitterkit-123456://
 here 123456 is your consumer key don't use {}

Comment: Still showing the same error `Callback URL not approved for this client application. approved callback url can be adjusted in your application settings.`

Answer (score 4):

`twitterkit-{ConsumerKey}://` or `twittersdk://`

https://github.com/twitter/twitter-kit-ios/blob/b6eb49d149b056d826cbc4b53eaeb39a3ebd591e/TwitterKit/TwitterKit/Social/Identity/TWTRLoginURLParser.h

Answer (score 3):

I have used the following call back URL.

> twittersdk://

This work for me.

Comment: God Bless You :)

Comment: @Sudhansu I have only used "twittersdk://" in my twitter callback url .this is work for me.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add this callback URL under your twitter app settings